# How did I find out about this site before everyone else?

Tags: discussion, support

I thought I saw an email come across saying something about StackExchange and so I figured this site might be fully armed and operational.

But alas, I am the only one who seems to know about it.  Feels kinda like me at church in college, heheh. Anyway, hope everyone else gets the memo soon.

Answer (score 5):

Only people who followed and committed to the [site's proposal in Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11655/christianity) should have gotten notifications of the Private Beta.  The Private Beta period usually lasts about a week, after which any StackExchange user (or anyone else on the Internet, for that matter) can join the Public Beta.

More details are available here:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq

Answer (score 1):

This StackExchange site just launched beta.  I'm guessing an hour or so ago.